# how to show Array in PHP CodeIgniter with Driver ODBC and OS LINUX Redhat

Tags: php, odbc, codeigniter-3

this code running at OS WIndows use Driver sqlsrv

```
  <td><?php echo ($iss->Issuer); ?></td>
```

but cannot work at OS Linux Redhat with Driver ODBC, and the message show like this "Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$Issuer"
and this the models

```
function getIssuer($TID, $Acquirer) {
   $Issuer = $this->db->query("WITH CTE AS (SELECT rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.RelationTagID), p.RelationTagValue, p.RelationTag FROM tbProfileRelation p WHERE TerminalID = '$TID') SELECT DISTINCT (CTE.RelationTagValue) Issuer, prev1.RelationTagValue Acquirer FROM tbProfileRelation, CTE LEFT JOIN CTE prev1 ON prev1.rownum = CTE.rownum + 1 WHERE (CTE.RelationTag = 'AD02' OR CTE.RelationTag = 'AD002') AND TerminalID = '$TID' AND prev1.RelationTagValue = '$Acquirer' AND CTE.RelationTagValue <> ''");
   var_dump($Issuer);
    return $Issuer->result();
}
```

any can help me..
Best Regards, :-)

Comment: an array is an array. doesn't matter where it came from. And what you have ISN'T an array, it's a stdClass object.

Comment: but i don't know why that code runing on windows and error in redhat